# Catching errors for CIFilter.outputImage when using CIAztecCodeGenerator/CIQRCodeGenerator

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to create 2D barcode images with iOS and `CoreImage` using a `CIFilter` for `CIAztecCodeGenerator`. Depending on the length of the text and the error correction level settings, `CIFilter.outputImage` sometimes returns `nil`.
The following message is printed on the console only:

> Unable to create barcode. The message is too large for an Aztec
> barcode.

A similar message will be printed when using `CIQRCodeGenerator`.

Is there a way to catch this kind of error for `CIFilter` in code or find out in advance if the text will be too long to be processed?

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of the data depends on the correction level and also on the type of message that you want to encode. For example if your text only have numbers then a different encoding is used to put that data in the barcode and more characters will be allowed. You cannot really detect that specific error but you can always just check if the result was nil. If it was nil then probably beacuse message was too long.

According to documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAztecCodeGenerator :

> The full-size format can store up to 1914 bytes of message data
> (including correction) in up to 32 layers, producing a barcode image
> sized no larger than 151 x 151 pixels.

Also at https://help.accusoft.com/BarcodeXpress/v13.2/BxNodeJs/aztec.html you will find this 1914 bytes value. So probably you could assume that anything that is not larger than 1914 bytes should be successfully encoded by CIAztecCodeGenerator, but encoding anything above that size could fail.